# How can I locate the currently open tab in the project?

Tags: webstorm

In Webstorm I have a bunch of tabs open. How can I locate the file in the current tab within the Project tree?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are 2 ways to do this:

1. Navigate | Select In | Project View (Alt+f1)
2. 'Scroll from source' button in Project View toolbar (the leftmost one)

You can also enable 'Autoscroll from source' Project view option to automatically select the opened file in the Project view

Answer (score 0):

In 2019.03 version you can click on "**Always select opened file**" in menu under gear in project explorer